# Do Any Puran Or Hindu Texts Talk About Cultural Appropriation Of Hinduism In Kaliyug?

Tags: history, kali-yuga

Just wondering if the cultural appropriation of Hinduism by foreign societies in Kaliyug is predicted in Hindu texts ? Is mentioned anywhere ?

There are so many people in the west who teach yoga without any real understanding of it, has become a billion dollar industry.
Reducing it to people of the west in tight neon spandex showing off headstands and poses on social media.

Americans making huge bucks holding Tantra workshops, they profit and sell mantras to gullible westerners.

And they don’t know anything ??? And are not qualified to do any of it

Large numbers of American/European women selling “kundalini awakening classes” and “chakra meditations sessions” and “breathwork” retreats (pranayam, lifted from Indian yogis)

Zero ethics, zero knowledge of the Hindu scriptures where these things come from.

Zero respect for the years and years it takes for people in India who study this seriously and devote their lives to understanding it and teaching it.

Does this happen in every Kaliyug ? They steal all our stuff and just make tons of money from it ? While laughing at poor Indian people living in slums ??

Edit : Trying to make this post more clear in wording. My curiosity here is whether this sort of thing is predicted in Hindu texts for Kaliyug ? Could anyone clarify for me ?

Comment: It ain't our religion, It's everyone's. Let's be happy if they follow our Culture :-)

Comment: @Shashaank I’ll delete this post later and that’s the kind of reply I expected. The amount of ignorance and misinformation these people are spreading is astounding. The Tantra ones are probably the most extreme in how much they distort and misunderstand the original Hindu texts, which they don’t even try to find and look up. They tell Americans they know Sanskrit when they can’t even read basic Hindi. They pretend to be experts, they have no idea what they’re talking about, just cashing huge checks while tricking and fooling gullible western people. It’s pretty weird.

Comment: But I made this post wondering if this is predicted for Kaliyug in Hindu texts ? I actually don’t even know if Middle East & Great Britain attacking India and taking over the country is predicted, but those things also must happen to India in every Kaliyug right ? Cause chaturyug are kinda the same, kalp are more the same, then one full lifespan of universe repeats pretty exactly I think ? So all the same things of pillaging and plundering India must goes on in every Kaliyug, from what I understand.